# Right click press/release detection on MAUI

Tags: click, maui

I am migrating from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI, and I have a problem with left/right click gesture for Windows and MacOs.

I have a feature in my app which allows to make a gesture with click pressed, but the result has to be different for left or right click. However, using a `PointerGestureRecognizer` doesn't allow to detect if it's the left or right click. The `TapGestureRecognizer` allows to differenciate them, but only has `Tapped` as trigger, which doesn't allow to track pointer from the moment it's pressed.

Am I missing something? Is there another way to differenciate left/right click gesture ?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a known issue on GitHub regarding [Differentiate Left/Right click in PointerGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19617). You may follow it up.

Comment: Oh sorry you're right, I didn't see this post... My bad. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! Hope it can be fixed as soon as possible!